# Refactoring large Swift struct with mutating functions

Tags: ios, swift, refactoring

I'm trying to simplify a huge file in Swift and I'm not sure what would be the best approach. It might be a very naive question as I'm still fairly new to Swift :)

For the sake of simplicity, let's say I have one `User` struct and in it I can call a ton of different `setupModeA`, `setupModeB` and so on, called depending on various conditions:

```swift
struct User {
  var currentMode: String

  mutating func setupModeA() {
    currentMode = "A"
  }

  mutating func setupModeB() {
    currentMode = "B"
  }

  // and so on for each mode
}
```

I'd like to be able to take the `setupMode*()` functions and their associated helper functions into a separate file to make it easier to read through, since most of the time I'd be focusing on only one mode.

I was thinking:

```swift
struct ModeA {
  mutating func setup() {
    // change the mode from there
  }
}
```

**However I can't figure out how to simply pass and mutate the `User` info to this new struct.**

I thought about:

- initializing a bunch of `ModeX` objects with a `user` variable in the `User` struct and passing the `User` on init, but it creates weird behaviours.
- using static methods on the `ModeX` structs, but then I'm not quite sure how to mutate the `User`
- taking a more functional approach & not mutating the `User` but instead cloning it and re-assigning it each time... this would probably work but since my code is very sequencial it feels like added complexity / memory usage for nothing.
- switching from struct to classes and hoping it gives me other options... but I'm afraid everything would break
- really complex things that feel too weird and unintuitive to be mentioned here :)

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can move the functions to an extension instead (which you can have in a separate file) `extension User { mutating func setupModeA() {...}`. Maybe it is just your simplified example but why not have one mutating func that takes the mode as a parameter? And maybe you can make an enum of the modes?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson extensions could be a good idea, I didn't know about that ! And yeah it's a simplified example, in action each mutating function is changing dozens of params on the user

Comment: If you go with the route of having specific structs for setting up each mode then make the public method static that takes a user and returns a user (so non-mutating), `struct ModeA static setUp(_ user: User) -> User` and simply create a mutable copy of the inparameter

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thanks for the help! Would you advise going the multiple struct route, or the extension one?

Comment: It depends on how much common code you would have between the different modes but I would feel that using multiple structs as factories feels like a cleaner solution.